# How to add an empty slide in microsoft powerpoint while presenting?

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

I like the way PowerPoint gives features to the teacher to teach. I use it to teach my students. Currently, I add as many empty slides I may need to use it as a blackboard. But, suppose, I want to insert an empty slide in between, while presenting, is there a way to do it?

If that so, I might completely go with PowerPoint for my online classes.

If the default not allowing us to do it, is there any VB code to do the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Esteban's suggestion allows you to blank the screen, but the blanked screen won't allow you to draw on it (assuming that's what you meant by "use it as a blackboard". With VBA you can add a new slide though:

```
Sub AddNewSlide()

    Dim lCurrentSlide As Long

    ' Determine what slide we're on:
    lCurrentSlide = SlideShowWindows(1).View.Slide.SlideIndex

    ' Count the number of layouts in your slide master
    ' and determine which # is the blank layout
    ' Use that in place of 7 below if it's different
    Call ActivePresentation.Slides.AddSlide(lCurrentSlide + 1, _
        ActivePresentation.SlideMaster.CustomLayouts(7))

End Sub
```

Press <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd> to get into the VBA editor, add a new module and paste the code above into the new module.

Then go into your slide master and add a shape to it; give the shape an action setting of Run Macro (`AddNewSlide`)

During a show, clicking the shape will add a new blank slide after the current slide.
If you don't want the shape visible, you can give it no outline and a 100% transparent fill.

Comment: This work awesome.. Thanks for your code. I have one small query. It does adds an empty slide but it does not give me the shape to add more slides in the newly created slide. Is it possible to add that feature as well?

Comment: It inserts a slide based on the blank slide layout. You'll want to put a copy of the shape with the macro action on the blank slide layout as well as wherever else you've put it.

Comment: Can you please have a look at this question as well? I am trying to keep my presentation as neat as possible. https://superuser.com/questions/1542788/what-is-the-short-cut-to-change-the-pen-color-in-powerpoint

Answer (score 2):

You cannot add a slide while presenting, but you can blank your your slide by just pressing 'b' if you want it black or 'w' if you want it white. If you want to quit this, just press b or w again.
Good luck!