# What is the short cut to change the pen color in PowerPoint?

Tags: vba, microsoft-powerpoint

While I am presenting I would like to change my pen color and annotate on my slides. Is there way, I can find the hotkeys to change the pen color in Microsoft PowerPoint?

If there is no keys in powerpoint itself, can I find any VBA script to do that?

I have found a autohotkey solution in the following link. But I would like to use a macro inside my powerpoint itself, so that I can use it in Mac as well.

https://www.reddit.com/r/Surface/comments/61epja/switch_pen_colors_during_powerpoint_slideshow/

Comment: In Windows PPT, you can right-click to get to various pen options, including colors; seems like this would be more useful than hotkeys since you're drawing with the mouse/pen already and don't have to switch back to they keyboard.